# Find tag name in XML [PHP]

Tags: php, xml

I have XML from SOAP which looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ws="http://ws.axnbusiness.b2b.audatex.com" 
xmlns:typ="http://ws.axnbusiness.b2b.audatex.com/types"> 
   <soapenv:Header/> 
   <soapenv:Body> 
      <ws:uploadTask> 
         <ws:parameters> 
            <item> 
               <key>loginId</key> 
               <value>sales@audatex.cz</value> 
            </item> 
            <item> 
               <key>password</key> 
               <value>Sales123</value> 
            </item> 
         </ws:parameters>
```

I need to read first child tag name of `<soapenv:body>`.
In general response should be something like: `ws:uploadTask`

This value represent name of acction which should take with that XML, so name of it will be different.

I tryed to atleast check if tag even exist by something like:

```
$doc->loadXml($xml);
$doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('ws:uploadTask', '*')
```

But without success, is there anyone who can help me how to get something like this?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, it has been a while since i worked with XML, but if you are using DOMDocument for xml parsing, try searchin for the element without the namespace (ws:). namespaces in DOmDocument sometimes work very strangely. If your node names will change you should not rely on names, use `$doc->childNodes`  and then foreach them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should use the [Soap extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). Soap is an XML format and can be parsed using an XML parser, but it is easier to use the specific extensions and objects for it.

If you try to parse it with DOM, you need to understand namespaces.

You are calling:

```
$doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('ws:uploadTask', '*');
```

This is the correct method to get an element node with a namespace. But `ws:uploadTask` is a node name and includes the namespace prefix. The actual namespace is the value of the `xmlns:ws` attribute. The attribute defines an alias `ws` for the namespace. The XML parser resolves this internally to the namespace URI again. You can read `ws:uploadTask` as `{http://ws.axnbusiness.b2b.audatex.com}:uploadTask`. So to get an element with the local name `uploadTask` in that namespace you call:

```
$doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://ws.axnbusiness.b2b.audatex.com', 'uploadTask');
```

However here is an easier method to fetch data from a DOM - use the `DOMXpath` object. Xpath expressions can fetch nodes and scalar values from a DOM document.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($soapXml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xpath->registerNamespace('ws', 'http://ws.axnbusiness.b2b.audatex.com');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('count(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:uploadTask) > 0')
);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

`DOMXpath::registerNamespace()` registers namespace aliases for the expressions. That can be the same alias/prefix like in the document or a different one.

### The Xpath Expression

Fetch the `uploadTask` nodes ...

`/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:uploadTask`

... count them ...

`count(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:uploadTask)`

... validate that the count is greater then zero

`count(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:uploadTask) > 0`

Comment: Thank you, for this really nice explenation :)